# Python & BS4 | get all table data with specific text content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new with Python and web scraping and therefore ask the following question.

I want to get only the tables with specific content in it.

This is how the HTML looks: 
It is not the first Table in this script so I want to select

```
    </TABLE></TD></TR>
    <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN=7 class='x2'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x3'>
    EingangsdatumDMYY</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x4'>
    Techniker</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x5'>
    Techn.</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x6'>
    Kunde</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x7'>
    OffAuftrag</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x8'>
    Planungsdatum</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x8'>
    Herstellerreferenz</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD class='x9_0'>
    DATE </TD>
    <TD class='x10_0'>
    default</TD>
    <TD class='x11_0'>
    00000001</TD>
    <TD class='x12_0'>
    Company Name</TD>
    <TD class='x17_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product A**</TD>
    <TD class='x14_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class='x15_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD class='x9_0'>
    DATE </TD>
    <TD class='x10_0'>
    default</TD>
    <TD class='x11_0'>
    00000001</TD>
    <TD class='x12_0'>
    Company Name</TD>
    <TD class='x18_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product B**</TD>
    <TD class='x14_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class='x15_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD class='x9_0'>
    DATE </TD>
    <TD class='x10_0'>
    default</TD>
    <TD class='x11_0'>
    00000001</TD>
    <TD class='x12_0'>
    Company Name</TD>
    <TD class='x19_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product A**</TD>
    <TD class='x14_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class='x15_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
```

I know the calsses used in this code are weird but it is generated and can therefore not be changed.

Now the Code I used to get the HTML with BS4:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
quote_page = 'Website.html'

# query the website and return the html to the variable page
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)


# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findChildren('table')

my_table = tables[1]
rows = my_table.findChildren(['th', 'tr'])

print my_table
```

Now the issue:

I do get the first row, but I want to search through the whole website and search for every Table with the text "Product A" in it and save the parent  in an array.

For example:
When the code is done, the output would be:

```
<TD class='x17_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product A**</TD>

<TD class='x19_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product A**</TD>
```

So the code has to:
1) search through the HTML and search for the text "Product A"
2) Grab the parent Tag and save it in a variable.
3) Repeat through the whole HTML.

I gratefully accept every tip -

Thanks and best regards
Yanick L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex expression in `Bs4` for find elements that contains specific text.

If u want to search all the `td` that contains a specific string u need this

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = '''

    <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN=7 class='x2'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x3'>
    EingangsdatumDMYY</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x4'>
    Techniker</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x5'>
    Techn.</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x6'>
    Kunde</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x7'>
    OffAuftrag</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x8'>
    Planungsdatum</TD>
    <TD style="vertical-align:bottom" class='x8'>
    Herstellerreferenz</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD class='x9_0'>
    DATE </TD>
    <TD class='x10_0'>
    default</TD>
    <TD class='x11_0'>
    00000001</TD>
    <TD class='x12_0'>
    Company Name</TD>
    <TD class='x17_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product A**</TD>
    <TD class='x14_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class='x15_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD class='x9_0'>
    DATE </TD>
    <TD class='x10_0'>
    default</TD>
    <TD class='x11_0'>
    00000001</TD>
    <TD class='x12_0'>
    Company Name</TD>
    <TD class='x18_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product B**</TD>
    <TD class='x14_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class='x15_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD class='x9_0'>
    DATE </TD>
    <TD class='x10_0'>
    default</TD>
    <TD class='x11_0'>
    00000001</TD>
    <TD class='x12_0'>
    Company Name</TD>
    <TD class='x19_0'>
    1000000    ,STATUS, TECH, DATE TIME, **Product A**</TD>
    <TD class='x14_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class='x15_0'>
    &nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findChildren('td', text=re.compile(r'Product A'))
print(tables)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :D Can i also select the next td ?

Comment: now that you have found all the `td` that you need, and they are stored in a list you can select them using the list indexs. in the upper example they are stored in the `tables` variable so you can select the first using `tables[0]` and the second using `tables[1]`

Answer (score 0):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains to get a table with specific text.

```
tables = soup.select('table:contains("Product A")')
print(tables)
```

Table with td that has that if you need to be more specific where text appears but want whole table:

```
tables = soup.select('table:has(td:contains("Product A"))')
print(tables)
```